# TabContent in FragmentTabHost in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am noob in Android. I have setup the `FragmentTabHost` now I have a question there is ViewGroup `FragmeLayout` which named "tabcontent". What are is for here Any use of it ?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In TabContet is where you define the root element of each tab.
there is an example using a Scrollview and a Relative layout for two tabs in tabcontent.
I suggest you use a Tabhost as parent to your tabwidget.

```
 <TabHost
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

          <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

              <FrameLayout
              android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                  <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/tab1"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                  </ScrollView>

                  <RelativeLayout
                   android:id="@+id/tab2"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:orientation="vertical" >
                  </RelativeLayout>

            </FrameLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

after that, initialize the tab programatically in your activity lkie this

```
TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabs.setup();


    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Tittle");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab 1");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Tittle");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: This is different thing which you are talking. The way you are using has been deprecated now